# Which AD server will an LDAP session connect to?

Tags: active-directory, vb6, windows-server-2003

I have a question regarding the LDAP. In my application (coded with VB6), we are getting all the active directory users for a given domain. There are 3 active directory servers on the domain. My application is having some problem when it tries to retrieve the users from the AD using LDAP. I have an error handler but it never triggers, it just seems to loop when trying to get the users in an Array. It does not Always happens. I noticed today that one of the AD server is in trouble. The server does not seem to work properly (AD Wise). Since the server is a client's property, there is no way i can remove the server for testing purpose.

```
Dim ObjUserCollection() As String
Dim objAdControler As ADControler.ComControler

Set objAdControler = New ADControler.ComControler
ObjUserCollection = objAdControler.GetUserCollectionFromwithGroup(PersonalSecurity.Security.Site.GroupAccess)
```

The error handler does never proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have checked deeper:

https://serverfault.com/questions/762699/load-balancing-ldap-from-a-domain-controller-via-f5

since my application does bind on the domain, it may or may not send the LDAP request on the faulted Active Directory.